# Error when attempting to rasterize vector layer in QGIS "ERROR CODE 127"

Tags: qgis, raster, error, rasterization, raster-conversion

I am trying to rasterize a vector layer of data, a pretty simple function in QGIS on my MacBook and it is popping up with an error message which I included in the screenshot below. I have had this issue before and never figured it out. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Error messages should always be included in questions as text, so that they're legible on all devices and can be searched by others later. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: The error refers to a non-existing path or directory `Applications/QGIS 2.app/contents`. It might be that your computer has some remaining environmental variables or similar from older QGIS installations.